# How to convert a m-by-m dataframe into m*m-by-3 dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame like this one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3,2,9],'B':[2,1,2,7],'C':[7,2,4,6],'D':[8,1,6,4]},index=['A','B','C','D'])

>>  A    B    C    D
  A 1    2    7    8
  B 3    1    2    1
  C 2    2    4    6
  D 9    7    6    4
```

I want to  change this data frame into pairs with the corresponding values, like this:

```
>> col1 col2 val
    A    A    1
    A    B    3
    A    C    2
    A    D    9
   ...  ...  ...
    D    C    6
    D    D    4
```

One way to do is to use the loop but that will be extremely slow with very large dataframes. There are questions asked which address the similar issue but for R. One way I guess is to convert the dataframe into numpy matrix and then use stack function. But I am not able to create a m-by-3 array from it. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.stack().reset_index()
df.columns = ['col1','col2','val']
```

Or numpy solution with [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html), [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) and [`ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
a = np.repeat(df.index, len(df.columns))
b = np.tile(df.columns, len(df))
c = df.values.ravel()

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':a,'col2':b,'val':c})
```

---

```
print (df)
   col1 col2  val
0     A    A    1
1     A    B    2
2     A    C    7
3     A    D    8
4     B    A    3
5     B    B    1
6     B    C    2
7     B    D    1
8     C    A    2
9     C    B    2
10    C    C    4
11    C    D    6
12    D    A    9
13    D    B    7
14    D    C    6
15    D    D    4
```

Solution with different order of `val` column with [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), for same order of columns add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = (df.rename_axis('col2')
        .reset_index()
        .melt('col2', var_name='col1', value_name='val')
        .reindex(columns=['col1','col2','val']))
```

---

```
a = np.repeat(df.columns, len(df.columns))
b = np.tile(df.index, len(df))
c = df.values.T.ravel()

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':a,'col2':b,'val':c})
```

---

```
print (df)

   col1 col2  val
0     A    A    1
1     A    B    3
2     A    C    2
3     A    D    9
4     B    A    2
5     B    B    1
6     B    C    2
7     B    D    7
8     C    A    7
9     C    B    2
10    C    C    4
11    C    D    6
12    D    A    8
13    D    B    1
14    D    C    6
15    D    D    4
```

Comment: df = df.stack().reset_index(), command doesn't work as it gives ValueError. Putting reset_index(drop=True) removes the error but the result becomes a pandas series and so df.columns doesn't work.

But, the numpy based method worked well.

Answer (score 2):

#### slicing

Similar to one of jezrael's answers.  The difference is that I create integer indices to slice with.  This enables me to slice the 2-D array `df.values` rather than `ravel`.  This is a matter of taste/preference.

```
n, m = df.shape
i = np.tile(np.arange(n), m)
j = np.arange(m).repeat(n)

pd.DataFrame(dict(
    col1=df.columns[j],
    col2=df.index[i],
    val=df.values[i, j]
))

   col1 col2   val
0     A    A     1
1     A    B     3
2     A    C     2
3     A    D     9
4     B    A     2
5     B    B     1
6     B    C     2
7     B    D     7
8     C    A     7
9     C    B     2
10    C    C     4
11    C    D     6
12    D    A     8
13    D    B     1
14    D    C     6
15    D    D     4
```